# Парсинг html

Tags: delphi, html, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток! Замучился с парсингом. Вот так получаю нужные данные:

```
var
  Doc, Arr, Elem : Variant;
  STag : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.OleObject.document;
  STag := Combobox1.Text;
  if STag = '' then begin
    ShowMessage('Тег не задан. Действие отменено.');
    Exit;
  end;

  Arr := Doc.getElementsByTagName(STag);
  for i := 0 to Arr.length - 1 do begin
Elem := Arr.item(i);
Memo1.Clear;
Memo1.Lines.Add(Elem.InnerText);
```

Но проблема в том, что если ответов на вопрос несколько, то их нужно записать одной строкой, а у меня каждый ответ с новой строки.

Подскажите идеи. Как получить ответы в одну строку?

**Обновление**

Я не совсем верно объяснил задачу. Дело в том, что ответы надо добавить в мемо построчно (каждый ответ с новой строки) но если ответов на вопрос 2 или больше их нужно вывести одной строкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что мешает в цикле не выводить, а соединять в 1 строку, а потом вывести всё в одной строке?

```
  Memo1.Clear;
  STag:='';
  For I:=0 To Arr.Length-1 Do
    Begin
      Elem:=Arr.item(I);
      STag:=STag+Elem.InnerText; //Можно ещё разделитель добавить +'; ' например
    End;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(STag);
```

Comment: я не совсем верно объяснил задачу. дело в том что ответы надо добавить в мемо построчно ( каждый ответ с новой строки) но если ответов на вопрос 2 или больше их нужно вывести одной строкой.

Comment: @stud
Суть вопроса, вроде, не поменялась после обновления. Чем вас не устраивает ответ?

Comment: Clear тогда уберите и добавьте счётчик ответов... Или вы снова не доступно объяснили

Comment: я извиняюсь за размытые объяснения,дело вот в чем, мне нужно "разобрать" хтмл на вопросы и ответы(допустим ответы в мемо1 а вопросы в мемо2),но так как на некоторые вопросы может быть 2 ответа то получается что ответов больше, то есть если на вопрос 2 ответа то их нужно записать в одну строку через запятую например

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/17174/stud Тогда вам нужно использовать принципиально другой подход, т.к. и вопросы и ответы у вас в одинаковых тегах с одинаковыми стилями
Я бы распарсил через регулярные выражения лучше

Comment: @Isaev спасибо за ответ!можно пример кода как через через регулярные выражения это сделать?

Comment: @stud Версия Delphi какая?

Comment: @Isaev  delphi 7

Comment: Для D7 берём RegExpr: http://www.regexpstudio.com/RU/TRegExpr/TRegExpr.html

Как с ним работать там есть хелпы на нескольких языках
С самими регулярками можно поиграться тут например: http://regexr.com/

В данном случае будет например работать для вопросов "<b><SPAN[^>]+>([^<]+)</SPAN>", для ответов ";<SPAN[^>]+>([^<]+)</SPAN>", но можно и более элегантно составить